# Autocomplete implementation in cakephp 2.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, autocomplete, cakephp-2.0

Hello Guys i am very new to cakephp and i want to implement autocomplete in my project. I have downloaded two javascript file jquery.autocomplete.js and jquery.autocomplete.min.js and placed them both in my webroot directory. i have a field named city in my database which i have to autocomplete.  the problem is my sutocomple is not firing or even not showing alert when key is pressed.

my javascript code is

```
 <script src="../../webroot/js/jquery.autocomplete.js" 
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../webroot/js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
 $(function() {
 $('#Usercity').autocomplete({
     alert("ashish");

    //dataType: "json"
    minLength: 1,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/User/autoComplete",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data, function( el ) {
                    return { label: el.id, value: el.city }
                }));
            }
        });
    }

   });

    });
  </script>
           echo $this->Form-
   >input('city',array('type'=>'text','label'=>'City'));


   Controller code


       public function autoComplete() {
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $query = $_GET['term'];
    $items = $this->User->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('User.city LIKE' => $query . '%'),
        'fields' => array('city')));

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $data[] = $item['Item'];
    }
    $data = json_encode($data);
    echo $data;
    exit;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To fix problem

> the problem is my sutocomple is not firing or even not showing alert
>   when key is pressed.

you need to load jQuery lib before autocomplete.js something like

```
<script src="../js/jquery-last.version.number.js"></script>
```

or if you want cakephp to do it for you (no need to write '.js')

```
            echo $this->Html->script(array(
                'jquery-1.10.2.min',
                'jquery.autocomplete'
            ));
```